# Customize text with input fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, input-field

Does anyone know how I would go about to fix the duplicates when clicking on the checkboxes?

```
<label><input type="checkbox" data-bValue="100" data-sValue="sV1" data-nValue="nV1" name="layers"> 100</label><label><input type="checkbox" data-bValue="200" data-sValue="sV2" data-nValue="nV2" name="layers"> 200</label><label><input type="checkbox" data-bValue="300" data-sValue="sV3" data-nValue="nV3" name="layers"> 300</label><label><input type="checkbox" data-bValue="400" data-sValue="sV4" data-nValue="nV4" name="layers"> 400</label><label><input type="checkbox" data-bValue="500" data-sValue="sV5" data-nValue="nV5" name="layers"> 500</label><label><input type="checkbox" data-bValue="600" data-sValue="sV6" data-nValue="nV6" name="layers"> 600</label><label><input type="checkbox" data-bValue="700" data-sValue="sV7" data-nValue="nV7" name="layers"> 700</label><h1 id="render"></h1>
```

My search makes me believe i must re-do it all, but I thought I ask here first.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swedoc/Lwr16wrt/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var scents = [];
    var notes = [];
    var theRender = document.getElementById("render"); 

    $("input[name='layers']").on('click', function(){ 

                $.each($("input[name='layers']:checked"), function(){            
                    scents.push($(this).attr("data-sValue"));
                });        

                $.each($("input[name='layers']:checked"), function(){            
                    notes.push($(this).attr("data-nValue"));
                });

                    theRender.innerHTML 
                    += "You’ve created a<br>" 
                    + scents.join(', ').replace(/,(?!.*,)/gmi, ' and') + " sValue with " 
                    + notes.join(', ').replace(/,(?!.*,)/gmi, ' and') + " nValue.";                        
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you are trying to do. I checked you fiddleJs. And their is more than one troubling things. So what exactly you see as a problem ?

Comment: Sorry my bad. If you check the checkboxes it keeps adds more values but dont remove the previous. So, it just stack values over and over again. I want it to update the text from "theRender.innerHTML"

Comment: @JBO Thanks for the replys but I think I solved it by adding theRender.innerHTML = ''; to inside of the $("input[name='layers']") and it seems to work now :) i guess it just need a reference to a default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is all about scope of variables. You need to declare your arrays inside your function and not outside.

Also remove the "+" from your `innerHTML +=`.

```
$("input[name='layers']").on('click', function(){ 
    var scents = [];
    var notes = []; 

    $.each($("input[name='layers']:checked"), function(){            
        scents.push($(this).attr("data-sValue"));
    });        

    $.each($("input[name='layers']:checked"), function(){            
        notes.push($(this).attr("data-nValue"));
    });

    theRender.innerHTML = "You’ve created a<br>" 
      + scents.join(', ').replace(/,(?!.*,)/gmi, ' and') + " sValue with " 
      + notes.join(', ').replace(/,(?!.*,)/gmi, ' and') + " nValue.";                        
});
```

Here is your fiddleJs corrected: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwr16wrt/23/

Comment: There you go! :)